# Rearrange a map in random fashion

Tags: java

I've a `SortedMap<String, String>` containing **key:ID** & **value:Name**.

Now I want to rearrange the elements of this Map in random fashion & store them in separate map.

```
// Get a random entry from the SortedMap.
String[] keyArr = student.keySet().toArray();
String key = keyArr[new Random().nextInt(keyArr.length)];

// Use a separate List<String> to store which key has been selected, so that they are not re-selected
```

But above method does not sound very efficient.

Please suggest.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to copy the `entrySet` into a `List` and shuffle it. This would give you the elements in a random order.

Now you can push those elements to a new `LinkedHashMap` - to preserve the random order. Something like the following:

```
final Map<String, Object> m = new TreeMap<>();
m.put("A", 1);
m.put("B", 1);
m.put("C", 1);
m.put("D", 1);
m.put("E", 1);
m.put("F", 1);
m.put("G", 1);
final List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> e = new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet());
Collections.shuffle(e);
final Map<String, Object> r = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : e) {
    r.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I got your question, but you should be able to do something like

```
Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List keys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);
for (Object o : keys) {
    // Access keys/values in a random order
    result.put(o, map.get(o));
}
```

Comment: You have to use a `LinkedHashMap` as you will find that a `HashMap` will reorder the elements. Also, using the `entrySet` is more efficient as you don't need to call `get` for each element.

Comment: I was changing the `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap` while you wrote your comment.